# Labels disappear zooming IN in Qgis 2.2 Composer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, print-composer, qgis-2.2

I have a simple map with a polygon Layer of 2 Polygons. Labeling is turned on, so is the option of "Show all labels for this layer, even if they collide".

In the print composer the labels keep disappearing if i zoom in! Also when I export as image (I tried with .bmp, jpeg and pdf) only one of the two polygon label shows up!?!

What the hell is going on? I get that sometimes labels dissapear when u reduce the scale and the labels run out of space, but by zooming in is new to me!

Is there an option in Qgis or the Qgis composer that I am overseeing?

Please help, this is driving me nuts!

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, found the problem:

One of the polygons had a geometry error. After fixing that, using the geometry validity check, all labels do show up.